# What does 192.168/16 mean?

Tags: ip, cidr

OK, this isn't really a server question in practice, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with server management.
What is this joke supposed to mean?: http://xkcd.com/742

Answer (score 14, accepted):

192.168/16 is a private block of IPs that aren't routable on the Internet. It means that the killer was inside the house!!!

Comment: Oh, they mean it as in 192.168.*.*? OK, I get it now!

Comment: Yes, the /16 is CIDR notation, it means a 16 bit netmask, or 255.255.0.0

Comment: If you're not familiar with CIDR notation, read this, it helped me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation